# Mount / Read the contents of a binary dump from a BIOS eeprom?

Tags: bios

I've been researching this topic for about 2 days now, but have not been able to find a solution for my requirement.

## Some Background:

I own a cheap Chinese CCTV DVR, which runs a really cut-down version of Linux. Once you configure the admin password on these boxes, it gets written to the BIOS eeprom. If you forget the password, you are very limited; you either try to use a password recovery tool (none of which worked for me) or you try to overwrite the BIOS .bin file with a new one, and hope that you have one which will boot the hardware correctly and recognise all the components on the motherboard. Been there, done that, didn't work (long story!) I've tried 3x different BIOS images that were very similar, but didn't fully recognise all the hardware on my MB.

I need to figure out where within the original BIOS filesystem the password was written, to see if I can recover it.

So....

I have a .bin dump from this BIOS chip. I obtained the .bin dump by using a CH341 USB Programmer. I desoldered the chip from the motherboard, and read it's contents. I 'think' (assume?) that it contains an MBR and some other partitions.

I would like to 'mount' this .bin file and be able to read the contents of the filesystem(s).

I have so far attempted the following:

1. Read the content of the file with HxD Hex Editor. Which shows me 'some' info, but it is not entirely useful.
2. I've used DD to write the .bin file to a USB Key
3. I then used 2x different file recovery utilities to read the contents of the USB Key.
4. Unfortunately, and whilst I learned stuff in the process, this merely resulted in the file recovery utilities recovering previously deleted photos and videos from the USB key. As opposed to actually reading the files I had written with DD.
5. I have tried booting GParted, and reading the content of the USB Key. It didn't recognise any partitions.

So,

How can I take this .bin dump and write it to a disk, or virtual disk file and read the contents? Like mounting a Linux partition?

You can find the .bin file here, if you want to play around with it. There's no sensitive data on it: https://drive.google.com/file/d/19epXpqNXnw5TfAj3lQKDtSYABqXgOM86/view?usp=sharing

Comment: While this is an interesting problem, I am on the fence if this question is appropriate for SU.

Comment: If this is not a good fit for SU, would you be able to suggest an alternative forum where I could raise this question? 

I brought it up here, because I suspected members of the community will have a fair amount of knowledge when it comes to mounting and reading different types of file systems under Linux. Cause basically that is all this is; a really cut-down Linux distro. (which has to fit onto a 16MB chip!)

Comment: thats why i didnt vote to close

Comment: There is https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com, and `binwalk` is well known there. Also note that this isn't the "BIOS", embedded Linux systems have a flash ROM with various parts of the firmware (usually bootloader, R/O file system e.g. squash-fs, R/W overlay filesystem).  Anything you can modify, like the root password, will likely be on the overlay filesystem.

Answer (score 2):

OK, so after further research and consulting with some other experts on filesystems, we've determined that this .bin image contains some compressed cramfs and squashfs partitions.

After yet more digging, and trying various different forensic utilities, I finally found on that worked and allowed me to extract the cramfs and mount them in Ubuntu. The utility is called https://github.com/ReFirmLabs/binwalk

I am now able to read the filesystem, and I believe I have found the file that contains the web interface password. It appears to be the /squashfs-root-0/etc/auth.dat file. Possibly a java json web token, but not 100% on that yet!

Comment: Great headway!  I was going to suggest that you go chat with the coreboot/linuxboot people.  They do this kind of stuff all the time.  Maybe if you drop into their IRC channel, they might help.  #coreboot and #libreboot on freenode.

Answer (score 0):

Some partitions, especially vast majority of system partitions on phones, they don't have any filesystem, so files on them can't be read, only .img dump. The same is with bios dump, it has surely files in it, but doesn't have any filesystem to read from it. Vendors are scared of letting people see some files (idk why, it's not source code). For example, libreboot and coreboot roms come with filesystem (corebootfs) and firmware files can be read and modified within rom.
Edit: I didn't read all posts from this article when i was writing this; yes, some firmwares (if not all) do have a filesystems, but it needs digging and you can't open this with usual tools.